# Connect derby database with .net

Tags: java, .net, database, derby

I've been searching for an answer to a question which is as easy to ask, as it difficult to find an answer:

1. Is there any possible way in .Net that I can use to connect to Apache Derby?
2. Is there any supported embedded database [with in local drive] as same as Apache Derby in .net?
3. Is there any supported network database [with in local drive on network] as same as Apache Derby in .net?

Comment: Read [this](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/techarticle/dm-0410ng/index.html). Seems its not easy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As .Net can't connect through JDBC and Derby doesn't support anything else I doubt you will be able to do this.

As you are apparently looking for an embedded Database you might want to have a look at Firebird: http://www.firebirdsql.org/

It does have a .Net connector if I'm not mistaken and you can run it as a network server, or a "file-base" embedded engine.

It is a very nice and capable DBMS (it has several features Derby does not have), the only drawback is that the documentation is a mess (there is no single complete manual that would cover the complete SQL syntax for the current version).

Comment: thanks for your solution! The firebird what u have said is correct .. my question is derby can be connected through db2 odbc driver as far as my research i just want to know any other way